# How would I specify a sort order for my data in my ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have an array that holds the ranks of playing cards:
A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K. (The "T" represents the 10).

I have all of these stored in an ArrayList.

For example, I have an ArrayList that represents the clubs and has all of the card ranks in it:

```
ArrayList<Character> clubs = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

If I print all of the elements in this ArrayList, they print out in the following order:

```
3 2 4 5 6 8 7 9 T J Q K A
```

I then added this to sort the collection:

```
Collections.sort(clubs);
```

With the collection sort, it prints the elements in this order:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A J K Q T
```

How can I make it so that it prints in this order: ?

```
A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 T J Q K
```

Comment: You can look into this http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: implement your own card class and implement comparable. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320678/class-for-representing-a-card-in-java you are not the first that implemented this ;-)

Comment: Instead of a Collection use Enums for the color and value of cards. Enums are using the order in which the values are declared, so no sorting needed.

Comment: use a map and give key values from 1-52 to every card , thus you can identify all of it

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid i wouldn't do that.... too much work... this is also a source for tricky bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement java.util.Comparator

```
public class CharacterComparator implements Comparator<Character> {
    public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) { 
        // ...
```

Then call sort

```
List<Character> characters = ...
Collections.sort(characters, new CharacterComparator());
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to use the comparator, but I got it working and it does what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            //write here the easy code to provide you the right order
            //return -1 if a should appear before b or 1 otherwise
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own [`comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public class CardComparator implements Comparator<Character>{
  public int compare(Character c1, Character c2){
   //implement your own logic for comparing.
   }
}
```

Once its implemented, you should invoke

```
Collections.sort(clubs, new CardComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution to implementing your own `Comparator` consider using [**Google Guava**](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). This library contains many helpful utility classes and functions.

It provides the class [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) which makes this quite simple:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

//explicitly state the ordering
Ordering<String> ordering = Ordering.explicit("A","1","2","K");

//create unsorted list
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("1","1","A","2","K","K","1","A");

System.out.println(ordering.sortedCopy(list)); //sort, but not in place

Collections.sort(list, ordering); //in place sort
System.out.println(list);
```